# Django: AttributeError: type object 'MyAppConfig' has no attribute 'rpartition'

Tags: django

I am trying to add `view_amodel` permission to my models. I decided to add the permission after migration. So I made following approach.

At an_app/**init**.py

```
from an_app.apps import MyAppConfig
default_app_config = MyAppConfig
```

At an_app/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.models.signals import post_migrate
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

def add_view_permissions(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    This syncdb hooks takes care of adding a view permission too all our
    content types.
    """
    # for each of our content types
    for content_type in ContentType.objects.all():
        # build our permission slug
        codename = "view_%s" % content_type.model

        # if it doesn't exist..
        if not Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type, codename=codename):
            # add it
            Permission.objects.create(content_type=content_type,
                                      codename=codename,
                                      name="Can view %s" % content_type.name)
            print "Added view permission for %s" % content_type.name


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    def ready(self):
        post_migrate.connect(add_view_permissions, sender=self)
```

When I do `python manage.py migrate`, I get following error,

`AttributeError: type object 'MyAppConfig' has no attribute 'rpartition'`

How to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reference to the AppConfig in the app's `__init__.py` is supposed to be a string, not the class itself.

Specify

```
default_app_config = 'an_app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

and remove the import.

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#for-application-authors).